# Spring conditional on qualified bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

**How can I use `@ConditionalOnBean` with qualifiers in Spring?**

Following self-contained example scenario: I have

- a service interface `SomeService`
- an adapter interface `SomeAdapter`
- a `GreenService` implementation of `SomeService` with qualifier `@Green`, depending on `SomeAdapter` with qualifier `@Green`
- a `BlueService` implementation of `SomeService` with qualifier `@Blue`, depending on `SomeAdapter` with qualifier `@Blue`
- an optional `GreenAdapter` implementation of `SomeAdapter` with qualifier `@Green`
- an optional `BlueAdapter` implementation of `SomeAdapter` with qualifier `@Blue`

@Green qualifier:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Green { }
```

@Blue qualifier:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Blue {  }
```

GreenService:

```
@Green
@Service
@ConditionalOnBean(value = SomeAdapter.class, annotation = Green.class)
public class GreenService implements SomeService {

    @Autowired
    @Green
    private SomeAdapter adapter;
}
```

BlueService:

```
@Blue
@Service
@ConditionalOnBean(value = SomeAdapter.class, annotation = Blue.class)
public class BlueService implements SomeService {

    @Autowired
    @Blue
    private SomeAdapter adapter;
}
```

GreenAdapter:

```
@Green
@Component
public class GreenAdapter implements SomeAdapter {}
```

BlueAdapter:

```
@Blue
@Component
public class BlueAdapter implements SomeAdapter {}
```

**Test to check the bean activation** (does not contain the `BlueAdapter`, therefore the `BlueService` won't be active):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {GreenService.class, BlueService.class, GreenAdapter.class})
public class GreenBlueServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @Green
    private Optional<SomeService> greenService;

    @Autowired
    @Blue
    private Optional<SomeService> blueService;

    @Test
    public void testGreen() {
        assertTrue(greenService.isPresent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testBlue() {
        assertFalse(blueService.isPresent());
    }
}
```

**Problem**: the test won't run, reporting a **missing dependency** (`SomeAdapter` with qualifier `@Blue` for `BlueService`). The `@ConditionalOnBean` should disable the bean as there is no `SomeAdapter` with qualifier `@Blue`, but this did not work.

I found out that when I add a `@TrueBlue` annotation (same as `@Blue`, but not marked as `@Annotation`) to the `BlueAdapter`, and use that annotation for bean activation on `BlueService`, it works like it's supposed to do (test all green).

In conclusion:

- conditional bean activation with required annotations works (in principle)
- it does not work however when the required annotation is a `@Qualifier`

Is this a bug, or per design, and **how can I achieve such a conditional activation that depends on a qualified bean in Spring**?

---

EDIT: @bruno-leite 's answer explains why it isn't working (annotation and bean type can match on different beans), but the remaining question is:

*How can you conditionally activate a bean if another bean of a given type AND a given annotation (or specific qualifier) are present?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please observe that the [@ConditionalOnBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html) documentation says:

```
All the requirements must be met for the condition to match, but they do not have to be met by the same bean. `
```

Pay attention to the part that says `but they do not have to be met by the same bean.`

---

The condition below will match if there is any bean from type `SomeAdapter` plus **any** bean annotated with `@Blue`

```
@ConditionalOnBean(value = SomeAdapter.class, annotation = Blue.class)
```

So, as you have the `BlueService` bean annotated with `@Blue` and you also have a `GreenAdapter` that is a `SomeAdapter.class` the condition passes. It tricks us into thinking that it would match only a `SomeAdapter` with `@Blue` annotation.

To make your example work just remove the `@Blue` annotation from `BlueService`

---

Have a look into `getMatchingBeans` method on `OnBeanCondition` class. You'll see that the conditions are evaluated separately.